# Android O bluetooth scan limit reached issue

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon

Trying to implement the periodic bluetooth scan in Android O.

The code is doing the scan every 15 mins and ending up getting the following error;

> 09-05 10:33:26.387 I: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1004)] GATT_Register 09-05
>   10:33:26.387 E: [ERROR:gatt_api.cc(1032)] can't Register GATT client,
>   MAX client reached: 32 09-05 10:33:26.387 E: Register with GATT stack
>   failed.

The code is as follows;

```
ScanSettings settings = (new ScanSettings.Builder()
                .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_OPPORTUNISTIC)).build();

BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScannerBroadcastReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("o-scan", true);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(BleUtils.buildScanFilters(), settings, pendingIntent));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What device model and oa version do you see this on?

Comment: It is happening in all the device model. Fixed it by doing the stop scan subsequently after the scan. This failure happens if we start scan and stop it once you start getting the results.

Comment: Tested with Pixel, Samsung S9, Note9 and Pixel2

Comment: Can you please clarify: "This failure happens if we start scan and stop it once you start getting the results. "

Comment: The assumption I had is whenever I start the scanning, the app always end up calling the broadcast receiver with the results. But when there is no devices around the broadcast receivers are not called. But my logic of stop scan is in the receiver. If we miss receiving the broadcasts exactly after 32 misses, the adapter reaches the limit and gives error response for start scan.

Comment: @SahayaGeorgeThanislas, did you solve your issue? I am also having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

This symptom often indicates that the Bluetooth stack has gotten into a bad state requiring a cycle of Bluetooth (or the phone) to recover.  Whenever you see this, first try turning off Bluetooth, waiting 30 secs then turning it back on to see if it recovers.

If you find the Bluetooth power cycle helps, you may be able to use the library's Bluetooth medic class to automate this recovery.

If cycling power to Bluetooth or the entire device does resolve the issue, there may be no other solution.  It is still worthwhile looking for patterns in when it shows up so that you at least know how severe the problem is.   Does it seem to be correlated with a number of beacons being detected?  How long does it take to show up after booting the phone?  Knowing te answers to these questions will at least let you know how bad of an issue you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but the solution that worked for me was like after stopping the scan just flush the scan results.

```
bleScanner.stopScan(scanCallback)
bleScanner.flushPendingScanResults(scanCallback)
```

for more information about the function you can visit here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner#flushPendingScanResults(android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback)